# How to attach Snackbar's lifecycle to fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using Snackbar in my app which has indefinite length. But when user leave this fragment i want my snackbar to gone. How can i do that? It's my first time working with snackbar. I used constraintLayout view from my fragment for it so i decided it's attached to fragment but why it's still exist after i leave fragment?

```
           Snackbar
            .make(binding.constraintLayout, getString(titleId), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.teal))
```

Comment: call [dismiss()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar#dismiss()) in `onDetach()`

Comment: @RickyMo but snackbar is not global variable

Comment: Then you just make a variable to store the `Snackbar` object returned by `Snackbar.make()`.

Comment: @RickyMo is it optimal? I thought there is more optimal decision like to really attach Snackbar to fragment using it's view somehow

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/BaseTransientBottomBar#LENGTH_INDEFINITE) states that "the Snackbar will be displayed from the time that is shown until either it is dismissed, or another Snackbar is shown." So you have to explicity call `dismiss` some where.

Comment: @RickyMo got it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a variable to store the `Snackbar` object returned by `Snackbar.make()`.
Then call `dismiss()` in `onDetach()`

```
class YourFragment : Fragment(){

    var snackbar : Snackbar? = null
    
    fun createSnackbar()
    {
        snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(binding.constraintLayout, getString(titleId), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            .setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(requireActivity(), R.color.teal))
        snackbar?.show()
    }

    override fun onDetach()
    {
        snackbar?.takeIf{it.isShown}?.dismiss()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer.I want to ask you additional question?why did you use takeIf there?I searched for takeIf and i learned if iniside of takeIf block true it returns object itself here snackbar but if it is null it returns null.But you used "?" and it also checks whether your object is null or not? That's why i thought takeIf unnecessary here.If you do not agree with me can you explain why did you use takeIf there?

Comment: @BarneyStinson I use takeIf to check if the Snackbar is shown. If it is not shown, do nothing. If it is shown, proceed to dismiss.

Comment: It might be redundant because it might be no harm to call dismiss on a snackbar that is not shown (I don't know, didn't check). But there might exists some other component that would throw exception when trying to dismiss when not shown. It is always safe to check before doing so.

Comment: Ok i get it thank you for replying me